# WordPress restricted page redirect for non logged users to login page with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I would like to redirect a visitor of a WordPress website to a login page when they are not logged in and on a certain page. I have the following PHP, which doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_redirect_if_user_not_logged_in' );
function my_redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( '3220' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.loginpage.com ' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) is the right hook to handle redirection.

Here is updated code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect_if_user_not_logged_in' );
function my_redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 3220 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.loginpage.com ' );
        exit;
    }
}
```